# Bisection method implementation in java

Tags: java

I am implementing the bisection method for solving equations in java.  I had initially coded the solution for a pre-defined polynomial equation x^3 + 4x^2 - 10.  Now I am generalizing the solution for any polynomial which the user inputs.

I read the coefficients of corresponding degrees.  Now I only need to tweak the f() method so that I can evaluate the f(a) , f(b) and f(c) .

```
// BISECTION METHOD IMPLEMENTATION IN JAVA
// This program uses bisection method to solve for x^3 + 4x^2 -10 = 0

package nisarg;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BetterBisection {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      double a, b, c; // a, b and c have the usual meaning
      double f_of_a, f_of_b; // f_of_a, f_of_b store values of f(a) and f(b)
                             // respectively
      int highest_degree;
      System.out.println("What is the highest degree of your polynomial? ");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      highest_degree = input.nextInt();
      for (int i = highest_degree; i >= 0; i--) {
         int coeff_deg_i;
         coeff_deg_i = poly_input(i);
         // System.out.println(coeff_deg_i);
      }
      // The following do-while loop keeps asking the user for a and b until
      // f(a)f(b) does not become negative
      do {
         a = input();
         b = input();
         if (f(a) * f(b) >= 0) {
            System.out
                  .println("Sorry the two numbers are not bracketing the root.  Please try again ");
         }
      } while (f(a) * f(b) >= 0);
      f_of_a = f(a);
      f_of_b = f(b);
      double root = bisectionMethod(f_of_a, f_of_b, a, b);
      System.out.println("Root is : " + root);
   }

   public static double input() { // Reads in the bracketing number i.e a and b
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a bracketing number");
      return (input.nextDouble());
   }

   public static double f(double num) { // Calculates f(x) given x and returns
                                        // f(x)
      final int COEFF_DEG_3 = 1; // Coefficient of x^3
      final int COEFF_DEG_2 = 4; // Coefficient of x^2
      final int COEFF_DEG_0 = -10; // Coefficient of x^0
      return (COEFF_DEG_3 * Math.pow(num, 3) + COEFF_DEG_2 * Math.pow(num, 2) + COEFF_DEG_0
            * Math.pow(num, 0));
   }

   public static double bisectionMethod(double f_of_a, double f_of_b, double a,
         double b) { // Does the actual work of evaluating
      double c; // the root using the method of bisection.
      double f_of_c;
      final double TOLERANCE = 0.0001;
      while (Math.abs(a - b) > TOLERANCE) {
         c = (a + b) / 2;
         f_of_c = f(c);
         if (f_of_c * f(a) == 0 || f_of_c * f(b) == 0) {
            return c;
         } else if (f_of_c * f(a) > 0) {
            a = c;
         } else {
            b = c;
         }
      }
      return (a + b) / 2;
   }

   public static int poly_input(int degree) {
      System.out.println("Please enter coefficient for degree " + degree);
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int coefficient;
      coefficient = input.nextInt();
      return coefficient;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question makes very little sense.  I think you either want to declare 12 variables or you want an array of variables.  You cannot use a for loop to declare multiple variables.  It would seem that what you want is: `public static final int[] COEFF_DEG = new int[12];`

Comment: 1) Your posted code doesn't compile. 2) Java has no global variables.

Comment: i need to declare 12 variable globally.  I don't want an array.  If I can't use a for loop how should I go about it?

Comment: I don't understand why it makes sense to declare twelve variables with some index i, yet it doesn't make sense to use an array (which could actually use the variable `i`).

Comment: i understand java has no global variables but I would like to declare 12 variables such that every method can access them.  How should I go about it?

Comment: @nisarg see the answer from Mureinik below. That's the best way to go about it. Wanting to shortcut using a for loop makes sense but Java does not support it. Best is to just declare 12 variables and be done with it.

Comment: If all the methods are in the same class, then create an array or collection in the declaration part of the class (outside any method or constructor), and you're done. If the methods are in different classes, then pass a reference to the class with the variables to the objects that need them, taking care to encapsulate things properly to thus avoid unwanted side effects.

Comment: Note that context would be nice. What are you using these 12 variables for? For all we know, yours could be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: I have elaborated the entire problem

Comment: Just declare any variables needed throughout the class as static fields. That's it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  I am sorry but I am a novice as of now.  I need 12 variables (which will hold the 12 coefficients coz 12 is the limit I am setting) which will be accessible to all the methods...so do I declare like so : static int var1; and so on in main?

Comment: Try it, see what happens. But it appears that you're not dealing with `int` here are you? You appear to need `double`, no?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tried static double coeff_deg_1 and it had an error next to it which said "Illegal modifier for parameter coeff_deg_1; only final is permitted"

Comment: You're trying to declare it **inside** of a method where it is only visible within the scope of that method. Again, you need to declare it in the **class** and outside of all methods. Declare them before your main method, just before the `public static void main(...` line

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels of this looks great now.  Let me try to finish the f() function now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use loops to define variables. Either have 12 explicit variables:

```
public class global {
    public static int coeff_deg_1;
    public static int coeff_deg_2;
    public static int coeff_deg_3;
    // and so on...
}
```

Or define a single array with 12 elements:

```
public class global {
    public static final int coeff_degs = new int[12];
}
```

Comment: -1 as global mutable state should still be avoided by all costs.

Answer (score 0):

here is a recursive one:

```
public static double f(double x) {
            return (x*x*x)-4*x-10;
}
public static double RecursiveBisection(Function fct, final double left, final double right, final double tolerance) {
    double x = 0;
    double dx = 0;
    if ( Math.abs(right - left) < tolerance ) // base case
        return (left + right) / 2;
    else { // recursive case
        x = (left + right)/2;
        System.out.println("Root obtained: " + x);
        dx = right - left;
        System.out.println("Estimated error: " + dx);
        if ( fct.f(left) * fct.f(x) > 0 ) // on same side
            return RecursiveBisection (fct, x, right, tolerance);
        else // opposite side
            return RecursiveBisection(fct, left, x, tolerance);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Bisection {
    
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static List<Double> coefficients = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private static double epsilon = 0.00000001; // precision.
    
    /**
     * Input the coefficients of the polynomial
     */
    private void inputPolynomial() {
        System.out.print("Enter the order of the polynomial: ");
        int order = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the coefficient of terms of the function: ");

        while (order >= 0) {
            double value = input.nextDouble();
            coefficients.add(value);
            order--;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The function method to compute the value of the function given variable x
     * 
     * @param x
     * @return result of inputing variable x
     */
    private double function(double x) {
        double result = 0.0;
        for (int index = 0, order = coefficients.size()-1; index < coefficients.size(); order--, index++) {
            result += coefficients.get(index) * (Math.pow(x, order));
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    private void calculateRoot() {
        double a, b;
        // Ask user for a and b until f(a) * f(b) > 0
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter the start of the interval: ");
            a = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter the end of the interval: ");
            b = input.nextDouble();
            
            if (function(a) * function(b) >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, the root is not within the 2 numbers.\nDo try again.");
            }
        } while(function(a)*function(b) >= 0);
        
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        double root = bisectionMethod(a, b);
        long timeUsed = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.printf("\nThe root is: %.6f.\n", root);
        System.out.println("Time used is " + timeUsed/1000 + " milliseconds.");
    }
    
    private double bisectionMethod(double start, double end) {
        double middle = (start + end)/2.0;;
        
        while (Math.abs(start - end) > epsilon) {           
            //System.out.println("x: " + middle);
            
            if ((function(start) * function(middle) == 0.0) || (function(end) * function(middle) == 0.0)) {
                break;
            } else if (function(start) * function(middle) > 0.0) {
                start = middle;
            } else {
                end = middle;
            }   
            middle = (start + end)/2.0;
        }
        return middle;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Bisection bisection = new Bisection();
        bisection.inputPolynomial();
        bisection.calculateRoot();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not explain why it works, how can one learn from it?

Comment: The bisection method simply determines the root of a polynomial by halving the start and end number inputted. The solution continually uses the average (of both lower and upper bound) to test if it's the root of the equation. The do while loop in the computeRoot method ensures the user of the code enters two numbers that form a lower and upper boundary for the root. This ensures that the root is eventually determined.